# how to get date of joining and employe name for previous 3 months to next 15 days in mysql

Tags: mysql

My requirement is I should get employee name for previous 90 days based on date of joining column till next 15 days.
Mysql query upto  here like this

```
select currdate()-interval 90 day
```

output is :02-01-2019
query :

```
SELECT 
    first_name, status, doj
FROM
    opl_employs
WHERE
   `doj` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

but this is not working for me

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below one -

```
SELECT 
    first_name, status, doj
FROM
    opl_employs
WHERE 
    `doj` between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 75 DAY)
```